# How to modify a masked array in place directly by assigning to it using advanced indexing

Tags: python, numpy, indexing, matrix-indexing, masked-array

I have an array that I want to change some values on some rows. The desired rows will be addressed by a Boolean masked array. Then I want to modify one of the values in the rows:

```
a = np.array([[0., 0.],
              [0., 0.],
              [0., 0.],
              [0., 0.],
              [0., 0.]])
mask = np.array([False,  True,  True,  True, False])
multi = np.array([0, 1, 2], dtype=np.int64)
ind = np.array([1, 0, 1], dtype=np.int64)
res = np.array([0.02238303, 0.01624808, 0.0234094])

a[mask][multi, ind] = res
print(a)           # --> [[0. 0.] [0. 0.] [0. 0.] [0. 0.] [0. 0.]]
# The desired result --> [[0. 0.] [0. 0.02238303] [0.01624808 0.] [0. 0.0234094 ] [0. 0.]]
```

I know I can do this by:

```
sample = a[mask]
sample[multi, ind] = res
print(sample)     # --> [[0. 0.02238303] [0.01624808 0.] [0. 0.0234094]]
a[mask] = sample
print(a)          # --> [[0. 0.] [0. 0.02238303] [0.01624808 0.] [0. 0.0234094 ] [0. 0.]]
```

Is it possible to do this job directly by indexing on the masked array something like `a[mask][multi, ind] = res`? How?

Comment: `a[mask, ind] = res` ?

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny Yes it works on this code . Thanks. I was confused in the code. Of course it will not work if `multi` not being as `np.arrange` e.g. `multi = np.array([0, 2, 1], dtype=np.int64)`. But, you can put as answer I get how to do.

Comment: I'm glad my comment helps, but I think an answer should adress why the second code is working. I'm not shure about this: `sample[multi, ind]` creates a copy, doesn't it?.

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny, `sample` is a copied slice of `a` and `sample[multi, ind]` is an *in-place* operation which apply on `sample`. So, the operation is done on a copied slice.  `sample[multi, ind]` didn't create any other copies.

Comment: Then `a[np.flatnonzero(mask)[multi], ind] = res` is a more general (but probably not nicer) working solution.

Comment: `a[mask][multi, ind] = res` is modifying an unnamed copy, not `a` itself.

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny, It is the true solution which will consider unarranged (unsorted) 'multi'. Please write your answer to accept if you would, it will shown to others this question is answered.