# Numpy: chained boolean indexing not properly updating boolean array without using np.where

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm writing a simple root finder in NumPy that is designed to operate on entire NumPy arrays simultaneously. The basic idea of the solver is that the array `not_converged` is the size of all the data points while `newly_converged` is a different array that is the size of the subset of `not_coverged that is` True` in that iteration.

I'd like to update the values in the overall `not_converged` array to be `False` when entries in the `newly_converged` array become `True`, but doing so using Boolean indexing doesn't seem to work as I'd expect:

```py
not_converged = np.array([True, False, True])
# A previously not converged point has now converged
newly_converged = np.array([True, False])
# Now update the converged state
not_converged[not_converged][newly_converged] = False
print(not_converged)  # should be [False False True] but the array hasn't been updated
```

I can get this to work if I use `np.where` though:

```py
not_converged = np.array([True, False, True])
# A previously not converged point has now converged
newly_converged = np.array([True, False])
# Now update the converged state
not_converged[not_converged] = np.where(newly_converged, False, True)
print(not_converged)  # Correctly updates the state
```

But I would have thought that the two methods above would yield identical results. Any idea why only the second method works?

Comment: Chained indexing `x[foo][bar] = value` only works if `x[foo]` produces a `view`.  Any sort of `advanced indexing` produces a copy, without access to the `x` data  base.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `np.where()` is equivalent to the following indexing.

Note that `not_converged[not_converged][newly_converged]` is not a view into `not_converged`, it's a copy, so nothing should change.

```
not_converged = np.array([True, False, True])
# A previously not converged point has now converged
newly_converged = np.array([True, False])
# Now update the converged state
not_converged[not_converged] = np.logical_not(newly_converged)
print(not_converged)  # should be [False False True] but the array hasn't been updated
```

Comment: Ah okay, I didn't realize that advanced indexing would return copy and not a view

Answer (score 1):

This question is similar to [one question asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71635287/13394817), as **hpaulj comments ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/users/901925/hpaulj), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/users/901925/hpaulj))** well explained the reason, you can do this as:

```
sample = not_converged[not_converged]
sample[newly_converged] = False
not_converged[not_converged] = sample
```

or in simple way use `~` to invert `newly_converged` instead `np.logical_not`:

```
not_converged[not_converged] = ~newly_converged
```