# How to change an array using advanced indexing and boolean array indexing without loops in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization, numpy-ndarray, array-broadcasting

**Problem:**

`A` is a multidimensional array of two dimensions `(i,j)` and `B` is a boolean array of the same shape that I want to define according to the values of `A`.

I want to define `B` through two broadcasting indices:

- `i_b` is an array that selects the indices of the first coordinate.
- `ij_b` is a boolean array that selects the indices j given i has already been selected.

**Code:**

The code I programmed:

```py
A = np.arange(50).reshape(5, 10) #shape: (i, j)
B = np.full(A.shape, False) #shape: (i, j)

#We pick first dimension
i_b = np.array([0, 2, 4])

#We pick second dimension given the first dimension has been chosen
ij_b = A[i_b]%2 == 0

#Change B according to i and ij
B[i_b][ij_b] = True

print(B[i_b][ij_b])
```

Output: `[False False False False False False False False False False False False False False False]`.

**The line `B[i_b][ij_b] = True` does not seem to change `B`. Why does it happen? How can I perform this operation to change `B` in a vectorized way?**

---

I know I can write a loop that works:

```py
for k in range(len(i_b)):
    B[i_b[k]][ij_b[k]] = True
print(B[i_b][ij_b])
```

Output: `[ True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True True  True  True]`

But then it stops being vectorized.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72822220/numpy-chained-boolean-indexing-not-properly-updating-boolean-array-without-usin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As metioned in the [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html#advanced-indexing):

> Advanced indexing always returns a copy of the data (contrast with basic slicing that returns a view).

We can solve the problem of the question (from [Numpy: chained boolean indexing not properly updating boolean array without using np.where](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72822220/numpy-chained-boolean-indexing-not-properly-updating-boolean-array-without-usin)), using:

`B[i_b] = ij_b`